# Azure DevOps Magento 2 Pipeline

Tags: php, azure-devops, composer-php, magento2, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am facing an error while I'm making CI of Magento using Azure DevOps.

```
In AuthHelper.php line 197:
                                                                               
  The 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/framework/magento-framework-  
  103.0.3.0.zip' URL required authentication (HTTP 401).                       
  You must be using the interactive console to authenticate                    
                                                                               

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [--audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]

##[debug]Exit code 255 received from tool '/usr/bin/bash'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/bash'
##[error]Bash exited with code '255'.
##[debug]Processed:
##vso[task.issue type=error;]Bash exited with code '255'.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[debug]Processed:
##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]
```

Here is my yaml:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  phpVersion: 7.4.3
steps:
- script: |
    composer self-update
    composer dump-autoload
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
  displayName: 'Install Composer'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: zip
    archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
    replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I have also used multiple commands for installing the composer

```
- script: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
```

This is one of them please have a look at these

Comment: And what's your question about this? Did you read the error message and try something to resolve it?

Comment: @NicoHaase the question is I am facing an authentication error and how to resolve the following error.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Where did you configure your credentials?

Comment: Did you try running the script on your local machine (without using Azure DevOps pipelines)? Did it throw the same error?

Comment: Nope it won't through an error because i am able to login into the account it might me an error because i am unable to login into the account if anyone can help me to. How to login into the account in azure devops

Answer (score 0):

```
- script: |
composer self-update
composer dump-autoload
php -r 'file_put_contents("composer.json", json_encode(array_merge_recursive(json_decode(file_get_contents("composer.json"), true), json_decode("{\"extra\": {\"magento-force\": \"override\"}, \"autoload\": {\"psr-4\": {\"Magento\\\\Framework\\\\\": \"lib/internal/Magento/Framework/\", \"Magento\\\\Setup\\\\\": \"setup/src/Magento/Setup/\", \"Magento\\\\\": \"app/code/Magento/\"}, \"psr-0\": {\"\": [\"app/code/\"]},\"files\": [\"app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php\"]}}", true), json_decode("$(composerOverride)", true)), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));'
echo '{"_comment": "These credentials were set up using some dummy Magento account", "http-basic": {"repo.magento.com": {"username": "017dbe6c70294588566ae2f1ab07398bb", "password": "ee15f7e08a2d91787554dfc5e668da16c"}}}' > auth.json
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

This script can be used to authenticate the user for Magento during azure devops pipeline

Comment: IIRC this is not how the Magento manual suggests. Please provide reference to the standard way and elaborate why this code fragment needs to be used / how your procedure is different. -- An earlier commenter also asked _how_ you're providing the credentials in the first place. You should put that information into your question already as otherwise future visitors could assume you weren't using credentials at all.

Comment: Provided Credential using bash script in the pipeline